Is it possible to get TypeGuard-like behavior for a function with NoReturn?
In python, we can use TypeGuard[T] to help a type checker narrow the type of other variables.
I am annotating an existing library that has a function, instance_check(), which is a wrapper around isinstance() that raises an exception if the instance check fails.
Are there any other mechanisms that I can use in annotations that help with narrowing the type of the argument in this case?
Desired behavior
I need a signature for instance_check that can be used in a .pyi file (so no inference), where the type of the first argument will be narrowed. E.g.
class Foo:
    pass

bar: Any = ...
instance_check(bar, Foo)
reveal_type(bar) # Should reveal bar as `Foo`

# This should narrow similar to below:
baz: Any = ...
assert isinstance(baz, Foo)
reveal_type(baz) # -> Foo

This works because the signature of isinstance allows it to narrow:
def isinstance[T](x: Any, t: type[T]) -> TypeGuard[T]: ...

The question is, is there a way of annotating, in an entirely .pyi-compatible fashion, the signature of instance_check, such that its first argument is always narrowed in subsequent code?
Why not -> TypeGuard[T]
The below code is actually incorrect (the use of NoReturn is spurious).
def instance_check[T](item: Any, instance: type[T]) -> TypeGuard[T] | NoReturn

The reason is, the actual implementation of instance_check returns None, not a bool. This violates the specification of TypeGuard, which can only be used for functions that return a bool.
This is for a stub file, so I can't change the implementation of instance_check to return a boolean. Even if I could, the False path would be unreachable anyway, though admittedly this constraint is less important.
Why not -> None ?
The point of the question is to narrow the type of the first argument.  This does not do so.
I am hoping to be able to narrow the type of the argument in code that follows a call to instance_check(). This is correct, since any code afterwards would only be reachable if the argument is of that type.
e.g. if we had this definition in the stub file:
def instance_check[T](item: Any, instance: type[T]) -> None:
   ...

Then this is what the code would reveal:
class Foo:
    pass

x: Any = ...
instance_check(x, Foo)
reveal_type(x)  # -> Any

Difference from possible duplicates
Type hint for a cast-like function that raises if casting is not possible
This question asks about properly annotating a function that casts its argument. There, the function in question is actually casting, so would return the new value with the casted type.
Here, the use case is different. The function being annotated has a completely different signature. The signature can't be changed, either, as the use case is in providing a stub file for a third party library that does not have types. When encountering a stub file, type checkers do not do any type inference. Thus, I can't write an implementation and have a type checker infer how it works.

I'm not sure I understand the issue. Can you please provide [mre]? Why def instance_check(item: Any, instance: type[T]) -> NoReturn wouldn't work for you?

@YevhenKuzmovych Because that would mean anything after that function is unreachable.

Oh, I see. Then it should be def instance_check(item: Any, instance: type[T]) -> None?

@YevhenKuzmovych I'm not sure how to improve the clarity of the question. I'm specifically trying to get type narrowing. NoReturn is incorrect, since it is only NoReturn in the case that the first argument is not an instance of the second. Otherwise, the return type is None. The correct type signature for the function is actually def ... -> None | NoReturn  However, this doesn't give me the type narrowing that I want. Ideally, the original code would have returned True rather than having no return. But I don't control that code, I'm simply writing a stubfile for it.

If a function raises an exception, it doesn't mean it has NoReturn return type as it can be used inside of try-except, but I get your point. I don't think you can annotate it the way you want it. I would use -> None | NoReturn. You're kind of trying to make the whole logic of the function into the type annotation.

NoReturn functions can be used inside try-except. NoReturn is commonly used for functions that always raise an exception.
I don't really need NoReturn. I'm just seeing if I can get some sort of equivalent to TypeGuard for this function, which really is a TypeGuard, it's just that it guards the type via a runtime exception rather than by returning true/false.

For assert-like functions, there's this idiom: value = instance_check(value, YourClass) (instance_check returns the first argument if it is of the correct type, or raises otherwise). This is quite a common question, so there's should be a dupe, but I couldn't find one just yet.

This question is similar to: Type hint for a cast-like function that raises if casting is not possible. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@InSync This is different from the linked question because it must be done entirely via annotations. This is for a stub file, in which all of the annotations must be present. We can't rely on the type checker's type inference.
I did mention this in my question, I can't edit the original code. This has to be done entirely in annotations.

What's wrong with just -> None? You only have to provide a type annotation for when it returns, you don't need NoReturn if it might raise an exception instead of returning.

@Barmar The question that I'm asking is how can I mark this function to narrow the
type of its first argument to the second argument, just like how assert isinstance() does. -> None provides no such narrowing.

What you're asking for is impossible in python's type system - variable type cannot be narrowed by call. It's the result of that call what narrows. The supported way would be either to "parse, don't validate" or to assert instance_check(x, Foo) - both are supported in python static typing, but you seem to already know both of these approaches. You have to give up some dynamic flexibility to use static typing in python, and this is one of such examples. Just -> None if you can't change the implementation.

Note that isinstance, (arg) -> TypeGuard[...], etc. don't type narrow by themselves - they must be a part of assert or if (see the typing specs). This indicates that you can't make a type-narrowing expression; type-narrowing must happen as part of a control-flow statement which tests truthyness to determine program flow (if, assert, match). To me, this is the real reason why it's not possible to do what you're asking.
